# How to convert AFNetworking service invoke to use AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: objective-c, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

This is my current call to (asmx) SOAP web service:

```
NSString *soapMessage =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
     "<soap:Body>"
     "<Save xmlns=\"http://www.myapp.com/\">"
     "<par1>%i</par1>"
     "<par2>%@</par2>"
     "<par3>%@</par3>"
     "</Save>"
     "</soap:Body>"
     "</soap:Envelope>", par1, par2, par3
     ];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myAppHTTPClientDelegate:didUpdateWithWeather:)]){
            [self.delegate myAppHTTPClientDelegate:self didUpdateWithWeather:responseObject];
        }         
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {            
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myAppHTTPClientDelegate:self:didFailWithError:)]){
            [self.delegate myAppHTTPClientDelegate:self didFailWithError:error];
        }
    }];

    [operation start];
```

But I need to change this to use `AFHTTPSessionManager`.
I suppose that I need to use this:

```
[operation POST:<#(NSString *)#> parameters:<#(id)#> constructingBodyWithBlock:<#^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)block#> success:<#^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)success#> failure:<#^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)failure#>]
```

But I am not clear about what parameters should I set?

UPDATE

```
NSDictionary *s_request = @{@"par1": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", par1], @"par2": par2, @"par3": par3, @"par4": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", par4], @"par5": par5};

    AFHTTPSessionManager* s_manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];

    [s_manager POST:@"http://192.168.10.26/mywebservice/myservice.asmx?op=MethodName" parameters:s_request success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"DONE!");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAILED %@, %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }];
```

This code always fail. Getting error `500`. Do I just need to add method URL or I need to add complete soap message somewhere. What I miss here?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass parameter in Dictionary like in the following example:

```
NSDictionary *request = @{@"email": self.email.text, @"password": self.password.text};
[manager POST:login parameters:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"DONE!");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to log in: %@", operation.responseString);
}];
```

Comment: That again use `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. I need example with `AFHTTPSessionManager`

Comment: It is the same as you pass parameter in operation you can pass in session manager as well:http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial(Check session manager)

Comment: What is `login` in `POST:login`?

Comment: login is variable which contain the url to post like for me it is login.php

Comment: I have updated question with some details can you please check.

Comment: Yes I did not think about the soap body. To pass soap body in your request you can check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716005/how-to-set-the-http-body-for-a-request-using-afnetworking